# Confusing resolution of a named argument

Tags: scala, named-parameters

A following code is giving me an error with Scala 2.11.7 which is confusing to me:

```
class A(val a: String, val bVal: Option[String] = None) {
  val b: String = bVal.getOrElse("")

  def copy(a: String = a, b: Option[String] = Some(b)) = new A(a, b)
}
```

The IntelliJ IDE is not showing any error, but on compile I get an error:

```
Error:(4, 52) type mismatch;
 found   : Option[String]
 required: String
  def copy(a: String = a, b: Option[String] = Some(b)) = new A(a, b)
                                                   ^
```

For comparison, this compiles fine:

```
class A(val a: String, val bVal: Option[String] = None) {
  val b = bVal
  def copy(a: String = a, b: Option[String] = Some(b.getOrElse(""))) = new A(a, b)
}
```

When I replace `Some(b)` with `Some(this.b)`, the error goes away, but it is still confusing to me why the error is there in first place. It looks like the compiler is resolving the `b` in the `Some` as the parameter of `copy`, not the `b` member of `A`. If this is the case, how can the second version compile without error?

Comment: If this is not just an example to showcase this interesting behaviour, the `Option[String]` type for `b` seams unnecessary when you only use the `None` case to define a default value (`""`) for `b`. It would be easier to define `A` as `class A(val a: String, val b: String = "") { ... }`.

Comment: @PeterNeyens It is only a showcase reduced from a much more complex real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has got to be a bug. The scope of the default expression includes previous param lists.

```
scala> def x = 1
x: Int

scala> def f(x: Int = x) = 2 * x
f: (x: Int)Int

scala> f()
res0: Int = 2
```

and `-Xprint:typer` shows the default is correct:

```
    class A extends scala.AnyRef {
      <paramaccessor> private[this] val a: String = _;
      <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def a: String = A.this.a;
      <paramaccessor> private[this] val bVal: Option[String] = _;
      <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def bVal: Option[String] = A.this.bVal;
      def <init>(a: String, bVal: Option[String] = scala.None): A = {
        A.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      private[this] val b: String = A.this.bVal.getOrElse[String]("");
      <stable> <accessor> def b: String = A.this.b;
      def copy(a: String = a, b: Option[String] = scala.Some.apply[A](<b: error>)): A = new $iw.this.A(a, b);
      <synthetic> def copy$default$1: String = A.this.a;
      <synthetic> def copy$default$2: Option[String] = scala.Some.apply[String](A.this.b)
    };
    <synthetic> object A extends AnyRef {
      def <init>(): A.type = {
        A.super.<init>();
        ()
      };
      <synthetic> def <init>$default$2: Option[String] = scala.None
    }
```

Yup.

```
scala> def y = "hi"
y: String

scala> def g(x: String)(y: Option[String] = Some(x)) = y map (_ * 2)
g: (x: String)(y: Option[String])Option[String]

scala> g("bye")()
res0: Option[String] = Some(byebye)

scala> def g(x: String)(y: Option[String] = Some(y)) = y map (_ * 2)
<console>:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Option[String]
 required: String
       def g(x: String)(y: Option[String] = Some(y)) = y map (_ * 2)
                                                 ^
```

Edit: the fact that the default method is correct doesn't mean much, since there are puzzlers related to the fact that the default methods are not very hygienic. E.g., http://scalapuzzlers.com/#pzzlr-051

Comment: OK. The bug is reported at https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9413 - I did not find anything like that in the tracker yet.

Answer (score -1):

You are correct in your understanding that when there is a parameter with the same name as a member of the surrounding type, the parameter will be preferred by the compiler.

In your non-compiling version, `b` is of type `Option[String]`.  This means that `Some(b)` is of type `Option[Option[String]]` which does not match the type of the second argument to the constructor of `A`.

In the second compiling version, `b` is still of type `Option[String]`.  However, `b.getOrElse("")` is of type `String`.  This means that `Some(b.getOrElse(""))` has type `Option[String]` which is valid for the second constructor argument to `A`.

Comment: What surprises me then is the runtime behaviour of `a`, which seems to be initialized as expected from the `a` member, not from the `a` parameter, which would be cyclical initialization and I would expect `null` or something like that, not the value of the `a` member. What is an explanation for this?

Comment: You are defaulting the `a` parameter to the `a` member.  So `copy()` will use the `a` member as will `copy(b = Some("str"))`.  But `copy(a = "str")` will use the `a` parameter, not the `a` member.

Comment: I am also surprised the parameter is visible in the parameter list at all.  [Named and Default Arguments in Scala 2.8](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/sids/rytz/Mon,%202009-11-09,%2017:29/named-args.pdf) states that " the scope of a parameter
extends over all subsequent parameter lists ... default expressions
can depend ... (but not on other parameters
in the same parameter list)."

Comment: What is the difference between defaulting of `a` and `b`? Why would the compiler take `a` member for the `a` parameter, but not for the `b` one? Is it because `b` is a part of a complex expression?

Comment: ooooooh.... I got wrapped around the axle a little.  I see where the confusion is now.  In that case, my answer sucks and I don't know. :)

Comment: Please tie your hair back before working with rotating machinery.

Comment: There's ongoing talk about distinguishing applications with named args, what does `f(x = x)` mean, where the trick is that `f { x = x }` will be assignment. It just goes to show how tricky all this syntax turns out to be. Isn't it just scopes?